# Upcoming 'things to watch' in physics

Tags: soft-question, big-list

What are the 'things to watch' in physics happening in the next year or so? 
E.g. A big astronomical event that happens only every n thousand years, or an experiment in particle physics which will validate or invalidate a theory, or ...

Comment: This is (nearly) impossible to answer because we cannot predict the future.

Comment: I think I haven't been very clear, I mean the sort of things we can predict or dates on which something will be launched, space shuttle launches or an important astronomical event or an experiment which people think might be important to a field of physics

Answer (score 2):

You never know! That's the fun part of it. Having said that, there are a few game changers that could happen within the next years, like LHC finding signs of supersymmetry, or a positive result from a gravitational wave observatory. Then there is the search for dark matter candidates, someone may find signs of non-Newtonian gravity at short distances, there is the question of the gravitational interaction of anti-matter. Neutrino masses are still not completely understood, there is the question of additional neutrino flavors, axion searches and lots more...

Comment: The release of the full Planck results later on should provide a nice counterpart to the recent BICEP announcement.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: Any bets?

Comment: [Good thing I didn't bet](http://edge.org/response-detail/26785).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: OK... is he saying that this puts a lot of restrictions on inflation models? That would be good news, if true. My bets were always on something else other than inflation, anyway, which doesn't mean there can't be no inflation, but it would be nice if inflation wouldn't wipe out any other signals of the really early universe before it happened.

Comment: Not really sure - it's not really my field, and I'm not really in a position to second-guess people with reasons to say that inflation happened. The whole hoollaballoo from last year does look a bit quaint now, though.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: I agree, it didn't get me excited, at all. When something experimental seems too good to be true... I can't judge, either, if and how the data constrains these models. Hopefully someone will write an easy to read review article.